# convert csv dict column into rows pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

my csv file contains two columns

1. Id
2. cbgs (dictionary key pair values enclosed by "")

**Sample Csv data looks like in notepad**
cell B2 Contains json key pair as string.

`id,cbgs 
sg:bd1f26e681264baaa4b44083891c886a,"{""060372623011"":166,""060372655203"":70,""060377019021"":34}" sg:04c7f777f01c4c75bbd9e43180ce811f,"{""060372073012"":7}"`

**Now trying to convert as below**

```
id,cbgs,value
sg:bd1f26e681264baaa4b44083891c886a,060372623011,166
sg:bd1f26e681264baaa4b44083891c886a,060372655203,70
sg:bd1f26e681264baaa4b44083891c886a,060377019021,34
sg:04c7f777f01c4c75bbd9e43180ce811f,060372073012,7
```

what i have tried

1.Attempt1

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, explode
import json        
fifa_df = spark.read.csv("D:\\1. Work\\Safegraph\\Sample Files\\Los Angels\\csv.csv", inferSchema = True, header = True)
fifa_df.printSchema() 
   df2.select("item",explode(parse("cbgs")).alias("recom_item","recom_cnt")).show()
```

> Error msg:
>
> cannot resolve '`item`' given input columns: [id, cbgs, recom_item,
>   recom_cnt];;

Per DrChess suggestion i have tried below code , but getting empty list as output.

```
fifa_df.withColumn("cbgs", F.from_json("cbgs", T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.IntegerType()))).select("id", F.explode(["visitor_home_cbgs"]).alias('cbgs', 'value')).show()






+------------------+----+-----+
|safegraph_place_id|cbgs|value|
+------------------+----+-----+
+------------------+----+-----+
```

Comment: what you need is `df2.select('id', explode(parse("cbgs")).alias("cbgs", "value")).show()`

Comment: add two more options to read.csv:--> fifa_df = spark.read.csv("D:\\1. Work\\Safegraph\\Sample Files\\Los Angels\\csv.csv", inferSchema = True, header = True, `escape='"', multiLine=True`)

Answer (score 2):

You need to first parse the json as a `Map<String, Integer>` and then explode the map. You can do it like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.types as T
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

...

df2.withColumn("cbgs", F.from_json("cbgs", T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.IntegerType()))).select("id", F.explode("cbgs").alias('cbgs', 'value')).show()
```

Comment: Not sure what went wrong.i'm getting empty result.can you look into it.

Comment: I suspect that the `from_json` is returning nulls which means that the explode will lead to an empty dataset. How does the content of column `'cbgs'` look like before parsing it using `F.from_json`? Maybe there is something wrong when the CSV is being parsed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what i followed. This involves only string handling operations, not complex data type handling.

1. Read the source csv file with `escape` option as `"` 
   `df=spark.read.format('csv').option('header','True').option('escape','"')`

```
|id                                 |cbgs                                                    |
+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|sg:bd1f26e681264baaa4b44083891c886a|{"060372623011":166,"060372655203":70,"060377019021":34}|
|sg:04c7f777f01c4c75bbd9e43180ce811f|{"060372073012":7}                                      |
+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

2. Second column is loaded as string rather than map. Now `split` the column
   `df=df.withColumn('cbgs',split(df['cbgs'],','))`

```
+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|id                                 |cbgs                                                        |
+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|sg:bd1f26e681264baaa4b44083891c886a|[{"060372623011":166, "060372655203":70, "060377019021":34}]|
|sg:04c7f777f01c4c75bbd9e43180ce811f|[{"060372073012":7}]                                        |
+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

3.Later, Explode.

`df=df.withColumn('cbgs',explode(df['cbgs']))`

```
+-----------------------------------+-------------------+
|id                                 |cbgs               |
+-----------------------------------+-------------------+
|sg:bd1f26e681264baaa4b44083891c886a|{"060372623011":166|
|sg:bd1f26e681264baaa4b44083891c886a|"060372655203":70  |
|sg:bd1f26e681264baaa4b44083891c886a|"060377019021":34} |
|sg:04c7f777f01c4c75bbd9e43180ce811f|{"060372073012":7} |
+-----------------------------------+-------------------+
```

4. Extract the values from cbgs column using `regex` --
   `df=df.select(df['id'],regexp_extract(df['cbgs'],'(\d+)":(\d+)',1).alias('cbgs'),regexp_extract(df['cbgs'],'(\d+)":(\d+)',2).alias('value'))`

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+-----+
|id                                 |cbgs        |value|
+-----------------------------------+------------+-----+
|sg:bd1f26e681264baaa4b44083891c886a|060372623011|166  |
|sg:bd1f26e681264baaa4b44083891c886a|060372655203|70   |
|sg:bd1f26e681264baaa4b44083891c886a|060377019021|34   |
|sg:04c7f777f01c4c75bbd9e43180ce811f|060372073012|7    |
+-----------------------------------+------------+-----+
```

5. Write to csv.